# Are string literal concatenation using + in log parameter store in compiler constant pool?

Tags: java

Consider the following

```
log.info("very long string  {}, " + " another string {}", a, b)
```

vs

```
log.info("very long string {}, another string {}", a, b)
```

In java specification https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5

String literals are stored in compiler constant and create in compile time

```
String x = "very long string " + "another string"
```

is equal to

```
String y = "very long string another string"
```

Both `x` and `y` share the same reference because they are literals that are evaluated at compile time.

But is that true if the string are part of perameter calls?

Comment: **Yes, indeed**

Comment: What do you mean? Provide an example.

Comment: Not sure it's relevant, but keep in mind a decent logger will not evaluate the String interpolation if the logging level is not enabled.  But, a concatenated String will likely always be evaluated (unless it's like your example with a constant compile time value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have a *constant expression*, according to the [JLS, Section 15.29](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29).

> Constant expressions of type `String` are always "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.

Your expression is made of string literals and the `+` operator, which are in the list of things allowed in constant expressions.

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> - Literals of primitive type (§3.10.1, §3.10.2, §3.10.3, §3.10.4), string literals (§3.10.5), and text blocks (§3.10.6)

*(snip)*

> - The additive operators `+` and `-` (§15.18)

There is no mention of any limitations based on context as to whether it's a constant expression, so even it's being passed to a method, it's still a constant expression, and it's still stored in the interned string pool.